# What should be the data type for an Image in Get-Set Java

Tags: java, jsp, types, get, set

I'm a newbie and I am learning all by myself by the JavaTPoint website, and I'm on this topic already http://www.javatpoint.com/registration-form-in-jsp.

What I am trying to do now is instead of User, I will add Car into my database, I understand everything, but there's only one thing that I don't have knowledge, the data type for Image. I tried to google the solution but it is confusing. I will show a little part of my codes focusing on Image, this is the Java class where I do the Get-Set part.

Can anyone help me what data type should I put in this Image File so I can put it in my CarDao(RegisterDao of the tutorial that I am following) so I can set it to

--> ps.setWhatDataType(9,c.getcarImage()); <--

*I declared this image in my MySQL as longblob as what I'm always seeing in some examples.*

```
public class Car {

private WhatDataType carImage;

public WhatDataType getcarImage() {
    return carImage;
}

public void setcarImage(WhatDataType carImage) {
    this.carImage = carImage;
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to use that returned information later. You can return link to image as String, you can also return array of bytes which represents data from image (if you later want to generate real image from them somewhere else and you know all necessary metadata). You could also return something like `java.awt.Image` or other subtype if you want to get object representing image.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is impossible or wrong sir? Thank you for correcting me early, I thought It will work the same way. I'll try to search in those stuff you said, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is tricky.  Storing images as binary fields in databases should be piece of cake, but in reality it is not.  Binary fields generally map to type `byte[]`, but the tricky part is converting an image to `byte[]` in order to store it into the database, and then converting back from `byte[]` to image in order to display the image.  If you really want to do this, I cannot help you, because it really depends on what kind of images you are dealing with.

If your assignment is not going to actually involve images, and you only want to implement the interface, then `byte[]` should do.

Another approach, which is pragmatic and easy, is to just use `String`, and have the string contain the filename of the image file.  In this case your database will not contain the actual binary data of the images, just their filenames.

Comment: I'm just following the steps in the JavaTPoint tutorial sir and I'm trying to do it with Cars instead of Person just to be different. I made a form to put there the inputs that I need and it is just my first time to include an image, using String will be interesting since I'll just rely on filenames? What should I type to learn that kind of approach? Thank you so much sir for noticing me :)

Comment: Just replace `WhatDataType` with `String`.

Comment: Also possibly call it `getCarImageFilename()` instead of `getCarImage()`.

Comment: Oh okay I'll try it, do I need to change the data type also of my carImage in my database? it's longblob in my database at the moment

Comment: May I ask also how can I do it when I attach the Image and then Add it to my database, how will it put directly on a path that I want?

Comment: Yes, you will certainly have to change the type of the column to something based on NVARCHAR.  (Depends on the RDBMS you are using.)  I do not understand your second question.

Comment: Thank you. I mean when I run my page AddCar suppose I've filled up the form and attached the img file already and when I click my Add button, I don't have any Path related code yet wherein the image I will attach will go directly on that specific folder so may I ask if you can advise me how and where should I put that path related code. Thank you master

Comment: Aha, I see, this is jsp, and you are uploading the image from a form in a web page.  Unfortunately, I cannot advise here, because I do not know how you obtain the image from the HTTP POST request.  But I am sure that the interwebz should abound with solutions that retrieve the POST data for you, check the file type etc, and then finally save the data into a file with an automatically generated unique name.